# Why does this async function run synchronously?

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
async function test() {
  console.log('TEST');
}

function go() {
  console.log('one');
  test();
  console.log('two');
}

go()
```

I've marked the `test` function as `async`, and I am *not* using `await` in the `go` method that calls it, so I expect the output to be this:

```
one
two
TEST
```

But the output comes out like this:

```
one
TEST
two
```

In my real use-case, `test` is a function that wraps some long-processing logic that I actually do want to happen asynchronously, not in-order.

Why isn't that happening here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think `go()` must be async and you should `await test()` inside go()

Comment: I tried modifying the test function and ran the code. I guess it satisfies your condition. 
Have a look:
function test() {
  setTimeout(function(){ alert("Test"); }, 3000);
}

Answer (score 9):

The body of an `async` function executes synchronously, until the first `await` statement. When it encounters an `await` expression it *yields* control to the calling function and is suspended. The part after the `await` expression is completed asynchronously.

As per the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> The body of an async function can be thought of as being split by zero
> or more await expressions. Top-level code, up to and including the
> first await expression (if there is one), is run synchronously. In
> this way, an async function without an await expression will run
> synchronously. If there is an await expression inside the function
> body, however, the async function will always complete asynchronously.
>
> Code after each await expression can be thought of as existing in a
> .then callback. In this way a promise chain is progressively
> constructed with each reentrant step through the function. The return
> value forms the final link in the chain.

This can be observed with the following example with no `await`, where the body of the function is executed synchronously:

```js
async function testSync() {
  console.log("Runs synchronously");
}


console.log(1);

testSync();

console.log(2);
```

Here is an example where an *awaited* Promise makes the behavior asynchronous after the `await`:

```js
async function testAsync() {
  console.log("Runs synchronously until here");
  await myPromise();
  console.log("Runs asynchronously here");
}

function myPromise() {
  return Promise.resolve();
}


console.log(1);

testAsync();

console.log(2);
```

This could be made to execute asynchronously in a number of ways. You can wrap your function in a `setTimeout` call:

```js
function test() {
  console.log("I want to execute asynchronously");
}

console.log(1);
setTimeout(test, 0);
console.log(2);
```

Or you can do it through promise callbacks:

```js
function test(){
 console.log("I want to run asynchronously");
}
console.log(1);
Promise.resolve().then(test).catch(e => console.error(e));
console.log(2);
```

Same can be done using `queueMicrotask`, docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask) :

```js
function test(){
 console.log("I want to run asynchronously");
}
console.log(1);
queueMicrotask(test);
console.log(2);
```

The difference between the `setTimeout` and the method using Promise callbacks is how they are queued for execution. There are two task queues, one is the task queue where the initial program execution, `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `requestAnimationframe`, etc callbacks are queued and the other is the microtask queue where promise callbacks are queued.

When you enqueue a task from the task queue and there are tasks still left, the event loop will check the microtask queue and execute them ***all*** before taking up the next task from the task queue.

Here is a snippet demonstrating this:

```js
function testTaskQueue(){
 console.log("Enqueued in the task queue");
}
function testMicroTaskQueue(){
 console.log("Enqueued in the microtask queue");
}

console.log(1);
setTimeout(testTaskQueue, 0);
Promise.resolve().then(testMicroTaskQueue);
queueMicrotask(testMicroTaskQueue);
console.log(2)
```

So depending on this, you can make your own *async* wrapper and pass your function to be executes as a callback:

```js
function makeAsync(callback, ...params) {
  //enqueued intask queue
  setTimeout(callback, 0, ...params);
  //Or using microtasks
  Promise.resolve().then(() => test(...params)).catch(console.error);
}

function test(...params) {
  console.log("I want to run asynchronoulsy", ...params);
}
console.log(1)
makeAsync(test, 3);
console.log(2);
```

Comment: How can I modify my `test` function to run asynchronously, out-of-order? Is there any way to do it without using `Promise` or `setTimeout`?

Comment: I figured out that I can get the result I want by inserting `await Promise.resolve();` at the top of my `test` function. But this seems hacky - is there a better way?

Comment: There are two task queues in JavaScript, one is a task queue where the initial program execution happens and also mechanisms such as `setTimeout` or `setInterval` is scheduled to be executed. So if you wrap your function inside a `setTimeout` ofr`setInterval`, it will run asynchronously. There is one more way of doing this, you can also enqueue the task in the *microtask* queue. this is the queue where promise callbacks are enqueued and hence the async functions are also executed.